# BQ ( Big Query ) SSH / Upload file from local machine to the table

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to use SSH to upload the file from local machine to EXISTANT BQ table.

This is the command which I use:

```
bq --location=EU load --autodetect --replace --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON mydataset.mytable .C:\***\conver.json
```

1) I have received this error - `FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'location'`

2) What is the correct way to set the path to the file from local machine??

**P.S.**
What I would like to do, is - manually upload JSON data file to EXISTANT BQ table

Comment: Is the dot before `C:\***\conver.json` deliberate? Which version of `bq` are you using? (i.e. what does `bq version` show?)

Comment: @DaisyShipton - BigQuery CLI 2.0.25,  about the dot, I have used the sample which was  ./mydata.json.

Comment: But that's providing a filename relative to `.`, the current directory. You're trying to provide an absolute filename. I'd definitely remove the period. If you do that, and remove the `--location=EU` argument for now, what happens? (We can come back to the location part when the rest is working.)

Comment: (It's not clear what SSH has to do with this really, btw.)

Comment: BigQuery error in load operation: Source file not found:   - What is the way to specify the local file?

Comment: I've just tried it, and it was fine. I just specified the fully-qualified filename on the command line. Are you *certain* that the filename you've specified exists?

Comment: @DaisyShipton  "C:\conver.json" I have tried this one, still no success ....

Comment: Well does `conver.json` exist in the root directory of the C drive?

Comment: Yes, it does exist )))) unless i'm blind)

Comment: So if you write `type c:\conver.json` instead, that shows the JSON? And the error is still "Source file not found"? What is your full command line at this point?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jz6rmt

Comment: @DaisyShipton I can show that this test file does exist in C:\ folder

Comment: You've put two backslashes there - why? Admittedly it still works for me with double backslashes in. Your screenshot doesn't show that `test.json` is present there though - what does `type c:\test.json` show?

Comment: What kind of shell are you using here, btw? If you're doing it from bash or similar, what happens if you do it just with a regular Windows command prompt?

Comment: @DaisyShipton It does work with normal cmd....... silly mistake.... thanks)

Comment: Please can you provide the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how my initial bq looks like:

```
bq --location=EU load --autodetect --replace --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON mydataset.mytable .C:\***\conver.json
```

The solution is ( which works for me ):

1) remove `--location=EU`

2) `.C:\***\conver.json`  should be without `.` at the beginning

3) DO not forget that section `mydataset.mytable` supose to be in this format `maindatasett:subdataset.table` basically same as if you will query this table. (by using web interface)

4) Run it through CMD (admin rights), with bq (gcloud) SDK installed

Solution was:

```
bq load --replace --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON maindatasett:subdataset.table "FULL_PATH_TO_LOCAL_JSON_FILE"
```